# Alert time discrepancies when synchronizing calendars between iOS 6 and OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, ios, ical, calendar

Mac running OS X 10.8.2 and iPhone running iOS 6. There is an issue synchronizing the alert times of events created on Calendar. Both devices are set so that the default alert times are 30 min before the start of the event.

When creating an event on the iPhone, with alert (say 5 minutes before the start) which is different than the default 30 min, after synchronizing it appears on the computer with alert time equal to the default (30 min before start) and not the 5 min as created on the iPhone.

When creating an event on the computer, with alert (say 15 min before start) which is different than the default 30 min before start; after synchronizing, it appears on the iPhone with two alerts, one equal to the created on the computer (15 min) and another, equal to the default (30 min).

In both cases, after synchronizing, the alert time stays as created on the device on which the event was created. After the second synchronization, nothing changes on either device, although there is discrepancy between the alert times on both devices. In iTunes, the checkbox in front of Calendars in "Replace information on this iPhone" is unchecked.

I am not sure if this started after upgrading to iOS 6 or OS X 10.8, as I upgraded within 1-2 weeks and didn't notice the exact time when the problem started, but the problem didn't exist with iOS 5.1.1 and OS X 10.7.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Edit: iTunes either via USB or Wi-Fi is used for synchronizing. Nothing in the settings has changed since upgrading the computer to 10.8 and the iPhone to iOS 6 (at least not changed by me, the new versions of the operating systems may have changed something).

Comment: Please add details about how you are synchronizing events. Are you syncing them via iCloud? Are you also syncing your iPhone to your Mac via USB or WiFi and iTunes? Are you trying to sync your Calendars via iTunes? A quick guess would be that you are doing both and that is creating conflicts. I recommend syncing Calendars exclusively via iCloud.

Comment: I am using iTunes, either USB or Wi-Fi, the issue happens regardless of whether USB or Wi-Fi is used. I am not using iCloud at all, it is not set on either device and is not an option for me. Will add that info to the question.

Comment: iTunes sync has a bunch of problems ([see my favorite](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48842/21703)) that iCloud doesn't seem to have.  That's why I recommend switching to iCloud.

Comment: I know of iCloud, but unfortunately using it or any type of remote sync (e.g. Google Calendar) is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can still reproduce this on the current version of iOS and OS X, this would be a great bug report to get engineering to fix whatever is causing the data to not sync.

You only need a free developer account to submit the bug report:

- https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

It looks from your description that you're not making any configuration mistakes, but I'd re-do both account setup steps before filing a bug to be sure your case is reproducible.

Comment: Reported this long time ago, nothing has changed even after upgrading to OS X 10.9 and iOS 7